# Twilight Domain - Steps of Night

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric

Good morning
I have a question regarding:

Steps of Night
TCE p34
6th-level Twilight Domain feature

> You can draw on the mystical power of night to rise into the air. As a bonus action when you are in dim light or darkness, you can magically give yourself a flying speed equal to your walking speed for 1 minute. You can use this bonus action a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

It does not clarify whether by leaving the darkened area the cleric can still fly.
It doesn't seem to follow the philosophy of the domain, so how should I get it used?
Sincerely